# Is there a way to keep data after passing the value through constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class that as a parameter get value with numbers. And inside that class I have a list that suppose to add those numbers every time instance of that class been created. How to make it work in Kotlin?

```
class MyClass internal constructor(
    private val number: Int
){

    private val listOfNumbers = mutableListOf<Int>()

    init {
        listOfNumbers.add(number)// So here it suppose to add all numbers
    }
```

Or maybe there is a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private val listOfNumbers: List<Integer> = listOf()

class Myclass {
init {
        listOfNumbers.add(number)// So here it suppose to add all numbers
    }
}
```

listOfnumbers will be shared, but only accessible within this file.

Comment: thank you but what is the difference with my code that I provided?

Comment: @BobRedity You're defining the val inside your class, so each instance gets its own instance, which will be initially empty.  I'm defining it outside the class, so it's a file level variable and will be shared between all instances.

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 3):

Right now every instance has its own `listOfNumbers`.

By putting the list inside the `companion object`, there will be only one, shared among all instances:

```
    companion object {
        private val listOfNumbers = mutableListOf<Int>()
    }
```

Comment: The negative of putting it in the companion object is that other classes will have access to it.  If you want that, that's fine (although high risk for misuse).  If you don't, just make it a file level variable rather than a companion variable.  Not every variable needs needs to be in a class in Kotlin.

Comment: @GabeSechan It can be `private` inside the companion object, as shown in my code. I suppose it still allows access through reflection, but that's true for all private fields.